# What is the difference between tweepy.API, tweepy.Client and tweepy.Cursor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, twitter, tweepy

I am new to Tweepy and came across these terms while reading the Tweepy Documentation. I am looking for the difference between the given three, more specifically in terms of **how Tweets shall be fetched in response to a *query*** along with the **limitations** in each case.

P.S.: The aim is to fetch a large amount of Tweets *(by >1 keywords)* in *minimum possible time*.

Answer (score 3):

[`tweepy.API`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/api.html#tweepy.API) is Tweepy's interface for Twitter API v1.1.
[`tweepy.Client`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/client.html#tweepy.Client) is Tweepy's interface for Twitter API v2.
[`tweepy.Cursor`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/v4.6.0/pagination.html#tweepy.Cursor) is Tweepy's interface for paginating through results from Twitter API v1.1.